# Cyclic Groups of Order 8 and homomorphic images

Tags: cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Show that the cyclic group of order 8 has as homomorphic images the cyclic groups of order 2 and 4 as well as itself and the trivial group.

Answer given: Find suitable normal subgroups and find the quotients

Hello everyone, I am doing a beginners group theory course and I was quite confused by the question and answer given above. Maybe the question needs rewording? But I am unsure how to approach this question as I am  unsure how to show a group has homomorphic images and  I am cannot see what cyclic group theorems I need to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Question asks "there is a homomorphism from the cyclic group of order 8 to the cyclic group of order 2; there is a homomorphism from the cyclic group of order 8 to the cyclic group of order 4; ... to itself; ... to the trivial group".

Comment: This is not an answer, but a hint really, a suggestion of how to do it. Considering a cyclic group is always Abelian, any subgroup will be normal. So just find subgroups of suitable order to act as kernels of the homomorphisms. Alternatively, the subgroups you find will also be cyclic and can serve as the homomorphic images.